# When can I write Mockito.anyInt()?

Tags: mockito

This is what I understand:

```
Mockito.when(list.get(Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn("Foo Bar");
Assert.assertEquals("Foo Bar",list.get(7));
```

Accidentaly, I saw that I also can do,

```
Mockito.anyInt();
Mockito.when(list.get(13)).thenReturn("Foo Bar");
Assert.assertEquals("Foo Bar",list.get(7));
```

But I cannot to the following,

```
Mockito.anyInt();
Mockito.verify(list).get(5);
```

instead of

```
Mockito.verify(list).get(Mockito.anyInt());
```

which is OK. Why not?

Comment: ``Mockito.anyInt()`` has no effect if it is just invoked but not used. It does not affect the first code snippet, you could drop line 1 of the first code chunk.

Answer (score 1):

Mockito.anyInt() is used for mock behavior recording or verifing.

`Mockito.when(list.get(Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn("Foo Bar");`

Means while invoking get on list with any Integer value "Foo Bar" string will be returned.

`Mockito.verify(list).get(Mockito.anyInt());`

Is correct usage and means that list.get() was invoked exactly once with any Integer value.